# Geolocation is not working on my react native iOS emulator

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, geolocation, react-native-ios

I used Geolocation in my react native code to get the current position and it is working well on Android. But not work on iOS.

Here is my code

```
import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";
import Geocoder from "react-native-geocoder";

_getCurrentLocation = () => {

    Alert.alert(
        "Get Location",
        "Do you want to update your location?",
        [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                style: 'cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'UPDATE', onPress: () => {
                    Geolocation.setRNConfiguration({ skipPermissionRequests: true,                                    authorizationLevel: "always" });
                    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') Geolocation.requestAuthorization();
                    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        info => {
                            const position = { lat: info.coords.latitude, lng: info.coords.longitude }
                            Geocoder.geocodePosition(position).then(res => {
                                console.warn(res);
                                const { updateUserState } = this.props;
                                updateUserState({ position : position, country : res[0].countryCode, city : res[0].adminArea });
                                this.setState({ position : position, country : res[0].countryCode, city : res[0].adminArea });
                            })
                                .catch(err => {
                                    console.warn(err)
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                                })
                        },
                        error => { 
                            // alert("Sorry, we cann't get your location now, please check your permission!")
                            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                            console.log(error) 
                        },
                        {
                            enableHighAccuracy: false,
                            timeout: 3000,
                            // maximumAge: 1000,
                        },

                    )
                }
            }
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
    )


}
```

I am getting the below error:

PERMISSION_DENIED: 1
POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2
TIMEOUT: 3
code: 3
message: "Unable to fetch location within 15.0s."

This is my info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to you location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to you location.</string>
```

Answer (score -1):

please set custom latlong in the emulator, Debug -> Location -> Custom
Location and set custom latitude and longitude and run the app agin

Comment: I just set the Custom Location and Latitude(37.785834), Longitude(-122.406417), and ran the app again. But the same result.

Comment: Location custom is not in Debug :

Features -> Location -> Custom Location
but is not the solution !